# Irregular layout in wp7 what can i do？

Tags: windows-phone-7, layout

See this [Chart](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=F3570949E7DCDDD4&id=F3570949E7DCDDD4%21303)

### rules:

### car1 car2

### car3 car4

If news has image then use car1 and car3 layout ;not image ,use car2 or car3 layout. If news has large image then it height equal car1 height + car3 height or car2 height+car4 height

My question: how use listbox dispose the Irregular layout in `WP7` ?

Comment: The link you provided says, access denied. Take a screen shot and upload it to any image sharing site like [this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/) and share us the link here

Comment: my reputation less 10 ,so i do not upload image now ,i upload the chart on SkyDrive ,url:https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=F3570949E7DCDDD4&id=F3570949E7DCDDD4%21303

Comment: Have a look at [WrapPanel](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth). May be thats what you need.

Comment: This is not Silverlight, but might give some inspiration: http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward answer to your problem. Shortly, you cannot do it readily. That is there is no "irregular" layout manager with the standard libraries (e.g. something like Grid or Stackpanel). Perhaps there is 3rd party library out there but i am not aware. If there is nothing out of the box, you have 2 options:

- Make each listbox item a 2x2 grid and then have some logic behind for hiding content of a cell when an adjescent cell grows its rowspan to 2. Vice versa when a big tile becomes a smaller one then you have to change the rowspan and make the hidden tile visible again. I am taking about collapsing or making visible here as an effect. But, you could of course remove the tile and append it to the end of the list. There are many options on how you want your list to behave.
- You could consider using a WrapPanel (from silverlight toolkit) inside a scrollviewer to achieve a similar effect. Again, you would have to do some work here as well for reorganizing the container.

Comment: hi，Gros Lalo，please give me specific example as said above ，use listbox item 2*2 gird show layout ，thanks

Comment: how use listbox Template and datasource behind how to bind to Template

Comment: The 2x2 grid approach require a bit of coding. Have you looked at wrappanel from silverlight toolkit http://silverlight.codeplex.com/ ?